# Can not read data from the store

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching a topic's title from the store, but I get this message

```
react-dom.development.js:14348 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ReadBlogPage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

This is part of my code

```
const BlogDahsboardPage = () => (
    <div>
       <TopicsListFilters />
       <TopicsList />
       <ReadBlogPage />
    </div>
);

export default BlogDahsboardPage;
```

and

```
const ReadBlogPage = (props) => {
    <div>
        <h1>{props.topics.title}</h1>
    </div>
}

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            topics: selectTopics(state.topics, state.filters)
        };
    };
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReadBlogPage);
```

How can I fix that error?
Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong:

```
const ReadBlogPage = (props) => { // true, Nothing was returned from render. :-)
    <div>
        <h1>{props.topics.title}</h1>
    </div>
}
```

You should use return:

```
const ReadBlogPage = (props) => { // <----- problem, use return or (
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>{props.topics.title}</h1>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error so props are null. Hmmm.

Comment: Wich props? Can you share some running example? Including selector.